# The multi-part identifier "DimProduct.Product_Category" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i try to create sp 
sp is

```
create procedure sprevgoods
as
SELECT DimProduct.Product_Category,SUM(totalsales)
FROM dimFact f
INNER JOIN dimProduct p
ON p.Poduct_key = f.Poduct_Key 
GROUP BY DimProduct.Product_Category
```

but it shows me error

The multi-part identifier "DimProduct.Product_Category" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the alias you assigned to the DimProduct table:

```
create procedure sprevgoods
as
SELECT p.Product_Category,SUM(totalsales)
FROM dimFact f
INNER JOIN dimProduct p
ON p.Poduct_key = f.Poduct_Key 
GROUP BY p.Product_Category
```

You may want to assign a name to the SUM(totalsales) column.